# How to toggle button with value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have 3 buttons with Y/N values. And 1 select box.
Following is the JSP code.

**JSP**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#BUTTON_1').on('click', function() {

    alert("### BUTTON_1=> " + $('#BUTTON_1').val());

});
});
```

```
<td>
    <td>
        <select id="selectBox" name="selectBox">
        <option value="R01"> NOT FINISHED </option> 
        <option value="R02"> FINISHED </option> 
    </td>       
</td>
<td>
    <a href="#"  class="btnA" id= "BUTTON_1" value="N">BUTTON 1</a> 
    <a href="#"  class="btnA" id= "BUTTON_2" value="N">BUTTON 2</a> 
    <a href="#"  class="btnA" id= "BUTTON_3" value="N">BUTTON 3</a> 
</td>
```

I have 2 questions.

1) How to code so that when I click on BUTTON 1, it toggles to name BUTTON 1_Y with value Y?

2) Only when all three buttons are toggled, so their values all change to Y, the 'FINISHED' option in select box appears. When not all three buttons have been clicked, or toggled, their values still remain as N and only NOT FINISHED option appears.

Im stuck on this for hours. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: can you not do that with javascript only?

Comment: I guess you can. I should have asked for javascript. I just edited the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JqxTG/)

JS

```
$(function(){
    $(".btnA").click(function(){
      if($(this).attr("value")==="N"){
        $(this).attr("value","Y");
        $(this).html($(this).html()+"_Y");
      }else{
        $(this).attr("value","N");
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace("_Y",""));
      }

      var $option = $("#selectBox option");
      //check if all button are toggled
      if($('.btnA[value="N"]').length===0){    
          $option.val("R02");
          $option.html("FINISHED");
      }else{
          $option.val("R01");
          $option.html("NOT FINISHED");
      }
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<select id="selectBox">
 <option value="R01">NOT FINISHED</option>
</select>
<a href="#"  class="btnA" id= "BUTTON_1" value="N">BUTTON 1</a> 
<a href="#"  class="btnA" id= "BUTTON_2" value="N">BUTTON 2</a>
<a href="#"  class="btnA" id= "BUTTON_3" value="N">BUTTON 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

So all you need to Do is:

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $allToggled = 0;
    $('.btnA').on('click', function() {
        if($(this).val() == 'N'){
            $(this).val('Y');
            $allToggled++
        }
        else if($(this).val() == "Y"){
            $(this).val("N")
            $allToggled--;
        }

        if($allToggled == $(".btnA").length()){ // length making sure this is done for as may buttons you have by the same class name
            $("#selectBox").val("R02").trigger("change"); // Note that trigger is written so that you may use the native event at later stage.
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<td>
    <td>
        <select id="selectBox" name="selectBox">
        <option value="R01"> NOT FINISHED </option> 
        <option value="R02"> FINISHED </option> 
    </td>       
</td>
<td>
    <a href="#"  class="btnA" id= "BUTTON_1" value="N">BUTTON 1</a> 
    <a href="#"  class="btnA" id= "BUTTON_2" value="N">BUTTON 2</a> 
    <a href="#"  class="btnA" id= "BUTTON_3" value="N">BUTTON 3</a> 
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btnA").click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="Y"){
            $(this).attr({"value":"N"})
        }else{
            $(this).attr({"value":"Y"})
        }
        var boolStatus = true;
        $.each($(".btnA"),function(i,item){
            if($(item).attr("value")=="N")
                boolStatus = false;
        });
        if(boolStatus){
            $("#selectBox").val("R02");
        }else{
            $("#selectBox").val("R01");
        }
    });
});
```

Or see demo 
[jsfiddle.net/xccbV/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/xccbV/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following javascript

```
$('#BUTTON_1').on('click', function() {
   if($(this).html().indexOf('Y') == -1 ) { // check if already clicked or not
     $(this).html($(this).html() + '_Y');
     $(this).val('Y');
     checkSelected();
  }
}); //add other button same like this

var checkSelected = function () {
    var toggle = true;
    $('.btnA').each(function () {         
        if($(this).val() === 'N') { toggle = false; }
    });
    if(toggle) {
        $('option.finished').prop('selected', true);
    }
}
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/Ss8a9/1/

updated html added classes to options

```
 <option value="R01" class="notfinished"> NOT FINISHED </option> 
 <option value="R02" class="finished"> FINISHED </option>
```